# How to add an element to Arraylist from another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

In the first_activity.java I have the following:

```
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now in the second_activity.java I want to do the following"

```
public void Method1(View view) {

    listItems.add("text");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Im trying to use a specif string from the second activity and adding it to the ArrayList from the first activity, what is the correct way to do so?

Comment: simple way is to define your `listItems` as static and then access it in your other activity as `fisrt_activity.listItems`. why adapter in your method?

Comment: Sorry, what you are trying to achieve is wrong!! 
When another activity comes up the old activity goes into a `pause` state. Calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will cause exceptions most time. The data(Array) has to be stored elsewhere and should be re-assigned to adapter during resume or `onCreate`

Comment: @Panther So im supposed to create the Array in another class and then use it? If so what is the correct way to edit it from another activity? Should I declare the adapter as outside onCreate method so i can use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onCreate` and on `onResume`?

Comment: @Panther Thanks it worked! i re-declared the adapter and resigned to list view in `onResume` , What is the correct way to store the Array tho?

Comment: Well, my mentor would say `Figure outdude`. So i suggest the same. Figure out. :) If you really need help. We are here :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a standard way, but give it a try, In your first activity put,

```
    static ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And in your second activity put,

```
first_activity.listItems.add("text");
```

But you won't be able to notify your adapter...
Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Thanks it worked, but what is the correct way or standard way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the new element back to the Activity 1 as a result of the Activity 2.

Check [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)